# Evaluate a limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus

Polya and Szego's book Problems and Theorems in Analysis contains a question concerning the evaluation of a sequence in general:
$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{a_1 + \sqrt{a_2 + \sqrt{a_3 + \cdots + \sqrt{a_n}}}}$, where $a_i$ are all positive. I wonder when we can actually evaluate the limit, although there is a sufficient condition in the book mentioned above for the existence of the limit. I even don't know the answer for the case $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Any comment is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: For the existence of the limit, there is a necessary and sufficient condition http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschfeldsConvergenceTheorem.html

Comment: OK. Thanks very much.

Comment: I have got the answer in the particular case $a_n= \frac{1}{n}$ by obtaining the inferior and superior limit, which are identical, i.e $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{1  + \sqrt{1/2 + \sqrt{1/2 + \cdots + \sqrt{1/2}}}}  = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}}$.

Comment: Using the fact that $\sqrt{a+b} \leq \sqrt{a} +\sqrt{b} $. We can think about when the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n ^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ is converge